# Arabic font not rendered properly iOS devices

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm using font name Hacen_Liner_XL, it's arabic font. 
I tested it on android and iOS device. iOS devices not render this font properly. Here a screen shots one on android and second one for iOS.

I have this format only .ttf 
 Here my CSS Code

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Hacen';
src: url("/new/fonts/Hacen_Liner_XL.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

html,
body{
    color:#333;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-family: Hacen, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEF24.png)

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DznoF.png)